# Aframe a-cursor has gone when entering VR mode on mobile

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

Aframe version: 1.0.3

Platform: android

Browser: chrome and firefox

The cursor (a-cursor tag) on mobile has gone when I enter VR mode.

Is there a way how can I enable/add the cursor when its on VR mode? or

Why the cursor has gone when I enter the VR mode.

```
    <a-assets style="display:none;visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;" ></a-assets>

    <a-sky id="sky" radius="90" src="" rotation="-3.7000000000000006 192.27000000000004 -3.58" material="" geometry=""
    animation__fadeIn="property: material.color; type:color; from:#ffffff; to:#000000; dur: 500; dir: normal; easing: easeInSine; startEvents:fadeIn"
    animation__fadeOut="property: material.color; type:color; from:#000000; to:#ffffff; dur: 500; dir: normal; easing: easeInSine; startEvents:fadeOut"></a-sky>


    <a-camera wasd-controls-enabled="false" mouse-cursor="" active="true" look-controls="" wasd-controls="" data-aframe-inspector-original-camera="" device-orientation-permission-ui="">

        <a-cursor id="cursorBlack" fuse="true" fuse-timeout="2000" raycaster="objects: .clickable" geometry="radiusOuter: 0.04; radiusInner: 0.00001" material="color: black" position="0 0 -2" opacity="0.5" visible="" cursor=""></a-cursor>

        <a-cursor id="mouseCursor"  raycaster="objects: .clickable; useWorldCoordinates: true" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"></a-cursor>

        <a-entity id="cursorBlue" position="0 0 -2" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.09; radiusOuter: 0.1; thetaStart: 90" material="color: #439DC2" visible="false"
        animation__loadCursor="property: geometry.thetaLength;  from:360; to:1; dur: 2000; dir: normal; easing: easeInSine; startEvents:loadCursor">
        </a-entity>
    </a-camera>

    <a-entity style="display:none; visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;" id = "sceneContainer" visible = "true"></a-entity>

</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug that has been fixed and will ship in the upcoming 1.0.4 version. You can use master builds meanwhile:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@2c5c131dccaab9d449fcd0383e98d027a5bc07f6/dist/aframe-master.min.js

Comment: Glad to hear. Flagging the answer as correct will be appreciated.